# RefreshDatabase is extremly slow

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I am using Laravel v5.6.26, PHPUnit 6.5.8, and PHP 7.2.9.

This is my full Test Class:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function basicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        $this->assertFalse(false);
    }
}
```

I call `phpunit` from homestead.

Without `use RefreshDatabase` this takes `513`miliseconds. With `use RefreshDatabase` it takes `17.29` **seconds**. I currently have 72  tables.

[image]

I only want to test one model that is associated to one table. It seems that refreshing the empty 72 tables is taking so much time. I tried to remove all tables except the one that I need, but `use RefreshDatabase` will always remigrate all the other tables.

How can I speed this up?

I don't think that the hardware is the issue here. Thats my PC:
Ram 32 GB, Intel® Core™ i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz × 8, GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2, I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64 Bit.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using RefreshDatabase? More specific, please share your real test (or something LIKE your test) to be able to discuss possible alternatives or flaws in your test.

Comment: @TimSch I have not written any tests for this project yet. I want to test models that are connected to the DB.

Comment: Migrating the database for each test is really slow, what you could do is create a new database only for tests, migrate your tables and then use the `DatabaseTransactions` trait.

Comment: @Remul thank you! The train `DatabaseTransactions` wasn't mentioned in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing). It now takes only 0.5 seconds. The migration part was the time killer. If you post an answer I will check it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you use `SQLite`, migrating the database for each test is really slow.

What you can do is use the `DatabaseTransactions` trait which starts a transaction at the beginning of the test and rolls it back at the end of the test.

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#working-with-databases) and this [blog](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/better-integration-testing-in-laravel-5.1-databasemigrations-databasetransactions-and-withoutmiddleware/).